# How to sort XML alphabetically by "company" before my ajax "each" loop

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

First off thank you to anyone who is so kind to give some helpful answers.

I am trying to get this XML to be sorted alphabetically by "company" before my each loop here.

Here is the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var html = '<table id="partners" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">';
 var html = html + '<tr>';

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "WellCityPartners.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function( xmldata ) {

    $(xmldata).find("Partners").each(function (index) {
html = html + '<td style=" background-image:url('  +  $(this).find("backgroundURL").text() +       '); height:100px; width:234px" align="center">'+  '<a href="' + $(this).find("hrefURL").text() + '" target="_blank">'  + '<img src="' + $(this).find("imgURL").text() + '">' + '</a>' +  '</td>' ;

 if ( (index + 1) % 3 === 0 )
 {
     html = html + '</tr>';
 }

 });
 html = html + '</table>';
 /*$( "body" ).append( $( html ) );*/
 document.getElementById("partnerTable").innerHTML = html;
}
   });
});
```

Here is a section of the XML:

```
<allpartners>
  <Partners>
    <ID>3</ID>
    <backgroundURL>images/BackgroundY.png</backgroundURL>
    <hrefURL>http://www.andis.com/</hrefURL>
    <imgURL>images/p01a.png</imgURL>
    <company>TEST</company>
  </Partners>
  <Partners>
    <ID>4</ID>
    <backgroundURL>images/BackgroundY.png</backgroundURL>
    <hrefURL>http://www.aurorahealthcare.org/</hrefURL>
    <imgURL>images/p24a.png</imgURL>
    <company>Aurora Healthcare</company>
  </Partners>
  <Partners>
    <ID>5</ID>
    <backgroundURL>images/Backgroundw.png</backgroundURL>
    <hrefURL>http://www.careersindustries.com/</hrefURL>
    <imgURL>images/p50a.png</imgURL>
    <company>My Industries</company>
  </Partners>
<allpartners>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [JQuery sort](http://www.wrichards.com/blog/2009/02/jquery-sorting-elements/) method on the array.  Something like this, maybe...?

```
    var nodes = $(xmldata).find("Partners");
    nodes = nodes.sort(myFuncToCheckCompanyName);
```

Then you can do your each() block.